# Loading two different jars in framework

Tags: java, classloader

I'm writing a new messaging framework for fun. The framework would receive events and call process(event) for each message received (Users implement an interface that defines a *process*() method.)

I'm currently running into this problem. Let's say my framework depends on a version of jar A and user code depends on another version of jar A (and the two versions are incompatible). I get NoSuchMethodFound errors.

I'm wondering what is the right way to solve this using Java class loaders?

Comment: You shouldn't have 2 versions of the same jar in the same classloader. Either use a custom classloader, either user OSGI for that. :)

Comment: You may succeed with using classloaders for two incompatible jars but such kludges last only so long. How about merging code from sources and then using just one jar? You can always reverse engineer the .jar files into .class and into .java then manually merge the codes and re jar them.